# Need to overlap divs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website setup using bootstrap and have the navbar done to my liking. Now I have to work on my container. I wanted something like this image here (http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d61zypfff). The main container overlaps the navbar a little bit. I have used these classes for my navbar and have laid out what I think would be the ideal layout of the code..

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation"></div>
<div class="container"> //Please do not add any styling to the container
    <div class="index"> //background: #ffffff;
        This text overlaps the menubar
    </div>
</div>
```

I have added extra padding-bottom to the navbar to make the navbar a little more "buff" and want my index section to overlap it.
Please let me know if I need to add more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add onto @isherwood, you must also set the `z-index: -1;`. This will make it so that the index div will overlap the navbar.

Comment: Thank you. I used isherwoods answer and then also set the z-index to -1. Everything seems to work now. Thank you @nahtnam!

Comment: @user3024194 No Problem. If you have any more questions feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 2):

A little negative margin should do it:

```
navbar {margin-bottom: -20px;}
```

Or:

```
.index {margin-top: -20px;}
```